# Reason for asp.net website error in one server and not in other server

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-6

I have a asp.net website which is deployed in a server A and same code has been deployed in server B.

The website in server A has problems while in website in Server B doesn't have any problems.

The problem is the sequence of order that the page is navigating is wrong while clicking on next button.

Its obvious that there is no problem with the code. So whats wrong with server ?

Posted next button code below :

```
    Try
        Dim currentView As Int16
        currentView = mvRequestorForm.ActiveViewIndex
        If currentView = 1 And isStoreSelected = 1 Then
            mvRequestorForm.ActiveViewIndex = (currentView + 2)
            rfv_view2_managersEmail.Enabled = True
            rev_view2_managersEmail.Enabled = True
        Else
            mvRequestorForm.ActiveViewIndex = (currentView + 1)
        End If

        If mvRequestorForm.ActiveViewIndex = 1 Then
            Sub_ActivateView1()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

My doubt now is ..i could see code for btn_View0_Next_Click  but there is no btn_View1_Next_Click

The issue is happening when i click view1_next

and i checked the event of view1_next and found that it is calling same btn_View0_Next_Click

Does it causing any issue ?

This is the code line :

```
Protected Sub btn_View0_Next_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_View0_Next.Click, btn_View1_Next.Click, btn_view2_Next.Click
```

Comment: What's the code for your button ?
What's the error (and exception if such a one is thrown) ?
Are the servers the same software/hardware wise ?

Comment: Please seee the question has been edited !

Comment: Ok, firstly its not obvious that there's no error in the code if you have empty Catch blocks - its very rare that you want to ignore all exceptions and almost certainly not in the code as above. Secondly are the servers identical - if not how not?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you catching and ignoring all Exceptions?  Is it possible that the server that's not working is throwing an Exception for some reason?

Have you walked through the code with a debugger on the server that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the records that you're navigating is different (e.g. different database) I think it's possible that the order in which your records come up from the database is different, like the records being inserted in a different way, or a different index being used, which could explain why the order is different from server to server.

have you checked that?